# Аутентификация пользователя с 3 попытками на winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, if, while

у меня задача сделать аутентификацию пользователя с 3 попытками и если пользователь введёт неправильно 3 раза свой логин и пароль то на 4 раз написать что ваша карточка заблокирована, с помощью цикла while. Я попытался это сделать но он не изменяет текст на нужный, я попытался добавить после цикла while if(i == 4) { ваша карточка заблокирована } но когда я запускаю форму и ввожу неправильно он пропускает все попытки и сразу выводит ваша карточка заблокирована. Вот мой код:

```
namespace WinFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string log = txtLog.Text;
            string pas = txtPas.Text;
            int i = 1;

            while (i <= 3)
            {
                if (log == "Dimas" && pas == "12345")
                {
                    lblRes.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblRes.Text = "Допуск разрешён";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblRes.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblRes.Text = "Допуск запрещён";
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                lblRes.Text = "Карточка заблокирована";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что не надо там цикл ставить, это же событие нажатия, зачем там цикл? Просто сделайте поле в классе, и при каждом нажатии при провале, делайте инкремент поля, если все правильно сбрасывайте его на ноль .

Comment: Я вам уже давал ответ но вы никак на него не отреагировали, поэтому ответ был удалён.

Answer (score 0):

Подумайте - в какой момент меняются `log` и `pas`? Они же не меняются внутри цикла `while`, так какой в этом цикле вообще смысл? Каждый раз при смене этих полей пользователь нажимает кнопку и происходит отдельный заход в метод `btnBut_Click`, нужно исходить из этой логики. Соответственно, описание и инициализация поля `i` должны быть снаружи метода `btnBut_Click`. Собственно, этого будет уже практически достаточно (по-хорошему нужно ещё порядок проверок поменять для красоты), поэтому код не привожу.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста коротко написать код, просто мне препод сказал сделать так чтобы после 3-х проверок выводилась надпись карта заблокирована

Comment: Для начала перенесите строчку `int i = 1;` из метода `Click` просто в сам класс. И ещё `while` поменяйте на `if`. Это то вы можете? И всё заработает. Не очень оптимально, но в целом заработает.